# How do I load a data-only dump created with pg_dump to another database?

Tags: postgresql-9.4, pgadmin, pg-dump

I have two PostgreSQL databases on my development server, one I use for development and another for production where I test my web applications. When I was using an earlier version of PostgreSQL I was able to easily create a TAR dump file of my prod database in pgAdmin and use that same TAR file to restore my development database after selection the option to clean the database first. A while back I upgraded pgAdmin to the version (1.20.0 I think) that is supposed to work with PostgreSQL 9.4. For whatever reason I cannot restore files in that version. I have tried TAR and SQL but the restore button is always protected.

I decided to use `pg_dump` and create a SQL file with only insert statements for my production database data. What I want to do is replicate what I was able to do in pgAdmin: Clean my development database and load my `pg_dump` SQL file into it.

I've search but so far I have not found any examples of how to do this in pgAdmin or in the terminal.

Comment: Don't use `INSERT` statements for your dumps (unless you have only a small amount of data).  `COPY` is virtually always (much) faster.  Furthermore, as I understand it, you need to use the `--clean` option of either `pg_dump` or `pg_restore`, depending on which dump format you choose.  It will throw away your tables before recreating them, so you need to do a full backup (not data-only).

Comment: Thanks @dezso. If you post this as an answer to my question. I will check it and post details of what I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are happy with recreating the tables upon restore (and I see no reason why one should not be happy :), then you could use the [`--clean` option](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html):

> -c
>   --clean
>
> Output commands to clean (drop) database objects prior to outputting the commands for creating them. (Unless `--if-exists` is
>   also specified, restore might generate some harmless error messages,
>   if any objects were not present in the destination database.)
>
> This option is only meaningful for the plain-text format. For the archive formats, you can specify the option when you call
>   `pg_restore`.

Use it with `pg_dump` when creating plaintext dumps, or with `pg_restore` when using any other format.  In both cases, you will need a full dump, as a data-only one would lack the information for creating the tables.

**Note:** don't use `INSERT` statements in your dumps (`--inserts` does this in `pg_dump`).  It is almost invariably slower than relying on the default `COPY` functionality.

Comment: Thanks so much!! This is what I did: I changed my backups by removing the --inserts clause. The databases reload a whole lot faster. For my purposes I usually want a mirror image of my production database on my development server. I was able to easily use the pg_dump SQL files from my production server to rebuild the production and development databases on my development server. This makes this process a whole lot easier. I guess pg_admin has bit the dust for me other than a quick way to view my databases or quickly drop them.